# How to trigger function only once after audio ends, p5.Js/Javascript

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have no idea what's going on. Here's the code:

```
 //pick random song
 if(mouseX>17 && mouseX<253 && mouseY>320 && mouseY<383){
     if(firstClick){
       nextSong();
     }
   else{currentSong.stop();}
   
   //reset button opacity
   timr=11;
   highlight.setAlpha(0);
   }
 
}
function mousePressed(){
 if(mouseX>17 && mouseX<253 && mouseY>320 && mouseY<383){
   click1.play();
 }
}

class song{
 constructor(song, cover){
   this.song=song;
   this.cover=cover;
 }
 
 play(){
   this.song.play();
   this.song.onended(nextSong);
   currentImg=this.cover;
 }
 stop(){
   print('stopped')
   this.song.stop();
   
 }
       
       
}

function nextSong(){
   
   print('played!')
   rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
   if(!firstClick){   //no duplicates
     while(currentSong==songs[rndm]){
     rndm = Math.floor(Math.random() * songs.length);
     }
   }
   currentSong= songs[rndm]
   currentSong.play();
   firstClick=false;
   //click2.play();
}
```

I'm trying to trigger the nextSong function only once whenever the current song ends(either on its own or by clicking a button) with this.song.onended(nextSong), but for some reason the function always triggers at least twice. I don't understand why, maybe it's too late and my brain isn't working idk. The only thing I can see triggering it is the one click in the mouseReleased function that stops the audio, triggering the start of another

Comment: can you let me know if I successfully answered your question, or if there is something missing or that isn't clear?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you are running into [a bug (#571)](https://github.com/processing/p5.js-sound/issues/571) that was fixed earlier this year, but there hasn't been a release since that time. One workaround you could use to ignore the extra event that occurs when you call stop is to check the `isPlaying()` function on the current `p5.SoundFile`. When you call `stop()`, the first `onended` callback happens while `isPlaying()` still returns true, and by the time the second happens `isPlaying()` returns false. When `onended` fires because the sound reaches the end `isPlaying()` also returns true. Here's a proof of concept:

```js
let snd;
let playStopBtn;
let i = 0;

function preload() {
    snd = loadSound('https://www.paulwheeler.us/files/TADA.WAV');
    noLoop();
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    
    snd.onended(() => {
        print(`fin ${i++} ${snd.isPlaying()}`);
        background('white');
    });
    
    playStopBtn = createButton('Play');
    playStopBtn.position(width / 2, height / 2);
    playStopBtn.mousePressed(playOrStop);
}

function playOrStop() {
    if (snd.isPlaying()) {
        print('stop');
        snd.stop();
    } else {
        print('play');
        background('lightgreen');
        snd.play();
    }
}

function draw() {
}
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.3.1/addons/p5.sound.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey thanks and sorry for the late response. I fixed my problem that night by adding song.playMode('restart') to my song class.